# Assign function and it's conditions to a variable for use later in script - R

Tags: r, variable-assignment

So I have a function that I want to use in multiple places in my script, but I do not want to repeat the script section over and over. Can I assign it to a variable like this?

```
  png(filename = "comparison_plot.png",
  units = "px",
  width = 1920,
  height = 1080,
  res = 150,
  bg = "white",
  type = "cairo")

  function <- png(filename = "comparison_plot.png",
                  units = "px",
                  width = 1920,
                  height = 1080,
                  res = 150,
                  bg = "white",
                  type = "cairo")
```

And then when I use it later in the script like this:

```
>function
```

It will call the function and do what I coded it to do:

```
  png(filename = "comparison_plot.png",
  units = "px",
  width = 1920,
  height = 1080,
  res = 150,
  bg = "white",
  type = "cairo")
```

Thank you all!

Comment: You were almost there. In case you do not change the parameters in your function you can create a function with an empty list of arguments. Hence, your code would look like: `myfun <- function() {mycode}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then write a function that does this:

```
make_comparison_plot = function(){
 png(filename = "comparison_plot.png",
  units = "px",
  width = 1920,
  height = 1080,
  res = 150,
  bg = "white",
  type = "cairo")
}
```

then you do `make_comparison_plot()` and it does the stuff in the *body* of the function.

Some notes:

- don't call your function `function` - its not descriptive and its also an R keyword for defining functions.
- You *can* make a bare word like `make_comparison_plot` do thing, but its better to create a function and call it with `make_comparison_plot()` (ie with the parentheses).
- So you've written a function that does one thing. You're probably going to want to do variations on that, so a better thing to do would be to put the arguments as defaults.

eg:

```
  make_comparison_plot = function(filename = "comparison_plot.png",
        units = "px",
        width = 1920,
        height = 1080,
        res = 150,
        bg = "white",
       type = "cairo"){
   png(filename=filename, units=units, width=width, height=height, res=res, bg=bg, type=type)
  }
```

and then `make_comparison_test()` will work just like it did before, but you can also try `make_comparison_test(filename="compare2.png")` and get a different output file. Or `make_comparison_test(filename="small.png", width=100, height=100)`. That's the power of writing functions.

Comment: That worked great!! Thanks! And also thanks for the advice, the default thing will be very useful in my script.